# virt-manager is not working on Ubuntu; there is no pop-up

Tags: networking, server, ssh, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I'm trying to use virt-manager (0.9.5) on an Ubuntu server (version 14.04).  I can connect to the Ubuntu server.  I connect to the Ubuntu server via Putty, TurboVNC, or via the IP Management Interface with a web browser and connect via a remote console.  When I use the virt-manager command, I go to the next command line.  There is no error and nothing pops up.  I configured Putty to Enable X11 forwarding.  The /etc/ssh_config and /etc/sshd_config files are configured to allow X11 forwarding.  libvirt and xterm have been installed.  virsh list shows VMs running.

"virt-manager --debug" returns an error about "Unable to initialize GTK: could not open display"

Why cannot I see a pop up after I use the virt-manager command when I am root?  I desire to have a GUI pop up to create a VM.

Update:  Xserver was already installed on the laptop. I changed the repositories the Ubuntu server pointed to and upgraded virt-manager to 1.2 with an apt-get command.  Don't apt-get commands install necessary dependencies?  virt-manager still isn't working. The upgrade worked (virt-manager --version proves it).  But this following command shows libosinfo is 2.9-1:

apt-cache policy libosinfo-1.0.0

I thought virt-manager 1.2 required libosinfo to be at 2.10.

virt-manager still doesn't work.  Why isn't virt-manager working?  If libosinfo wasn't installed properly with the apt-get install virt-manager command, how do I upgrade libosinfo?

Comment: do you have X-server running on your computer?

Comment: On the Linux server or the Windows laptop?  How do I tell for sure?

Comment: I had it installed the whole time.  I found that when it is properly installed, it doesn't have an entry in the "Uninstall Programs" section of Windows.  I reinstalled it for good measure.  But the problem remains.  Why did this question get downvoted? I disagree that every how-to has a section for installing X-Server.

Comment: Other possibility is that the X forwarding is disabled on server.

Comment: How would I test for this? /etc/ssh_config and sshd_config were configured appropriately as far as I know how to tell.  I examined them closely too.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have X server installed on you windows laptop. If you didn't install it on you windows laptop, you don't have it. It is part of every how-to.

Comment: It was already installed.